# How do I set the external editor for PostgreSQL's psql client?

Tags: postgresql

What do I put in `~/.psqlrc` file to set the default editor?

The editor I want to use ([Textmate](http://macromates.com/)) is at `/Users/username/bin/mate`.

I found the [place in the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-ENVIRONMENT) where they talk about it, and tried several syntax variations, but can't seem to get it to work.

For example, this didn't work...

```
\set PSQL_EDITOR "/Users/username/bin/mate"
```

In psql when I enter `\e` I get...

```
sh: /usr/local/bin/mate: No such file or directory
sh: line 0: exec: /usr/local/bin/mate: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I suspect `/Users/username/bin/mate` is a symbolic link to `/usr/local/bin/mate`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, it's a symlink. I tried setting it to the direct path to the executable. Same result.

Comment: Are you unable to change the default editor at all or is it just Textmate you can't change it to?

Answer (score 15):

Contrary to my comment above (which was the result of insufficient testing), you should put a line into `.bashrc` (or any similar place):

```
export PSQL_EDITOR="/Users/username/bin/mate"
```

In `psql` coming with PostgreSQL 9.2, there is a `\setenv` command, it is supposed to work from `.psqlrc` as well.

(Credits to [Pedro Romano](https://serverfault.com/a/433129/78246).)

Comment: This worked for me on Debian 7 with Postgres 9.3.

Comment: btw `\setenv` does not expect a `=`, it need to be written like that: `\setenv PSQL_EDITOR "/Users/username/bin/mate"`

Answer (score 3):

The first time you use editor psql asks you to choose one of them.

```
# \e
usage: which [-as] program ...
usage: which [-as] program ...
usage: which [-as] program ...

Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.
  1. /bin/ed
  2. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
  3. /usr/bin/code
  4. /usr/bin/vim.tiny

Choose 1-4 [2]:
```

The chosen editor is recorded at `$HOME/.selected_editor`.
If you choose the easiest one then this file is empty but if you choose another option then this is its contents:

```
# Generated by /usr/bin/select-editor
SELECTED_EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim.tiny"
```

Edit this file and you don't need to set any environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting it to whatever you type to run the application from the shell.  If that doesn't work, try running the editor from the shell to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

I use Notepad++ as a text editor.
Running Windows 10.

You need an `etc` folder in the Postgres root folder (this folder already has `bin`, `lib`, `data` if it's a server). Create a text file `psqlrc` (no file extension).

Contents of my `psqlrc` are:

```
\! chcp 65001
\setenv PSQL_EDITOR 'C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe'
SET CLIENT_ENCODING = 'UTF8';
```

Answer (score 0):

I am an windows user and want to set default editor as [Subtext]. Actually, I search a lot but none of them work for me. I finally discover that EDITOR or PSQL_EDITOR are environmen variables of psql, so I use command

> \setenv PSQL_EDITOR filename

It works for me.